# ar_track_alvar publication rate

Tags: ros, transform, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros-users,
is there a way to increase the publication rate of the provided tf Transforms: Camera frame (from Camera info topic param) → AR tag frame in the ar_track_alvar package?
I'm working on Ros fuerte.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187232/ar_track_alvar-publication-rate/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Hydro you can adjust the maximum frequency with dynamic reconfigure or with a 7th command line argument (which is not implemented in pr2_indiv_no_kinect.launch).

In Fuerte this seems not to be implemented.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0